# Haskell Cabal HUnit

Tags: haskell, package, cabal, hunit

I have a project in school where it is required to use

```
import Test.HUnit
```

I have installed it I cabal using

```
cabal install HUnit --lib
```

but when I try to run our code we get this error message:

```
Huffman.hs:8:1: error:
Ambiguous module name ‘Test.HUnit’:
  it was found in multiple packages: HUnit-1.6.1.0 HUnit-1.6.1.0
```

My first thought was to try to delete one of the packages and they will therefore not overlap. But when I use:

```
cabal list --installed
```

I cannot find the HUnit package. How can I delete it if I cannot find it??

(I am a beginner at Haskell and in programming in general)